# Wordpress search not working

Tags: wordpress, search

I have seen various topics on here and trying to follow but my site may be different but am not sure. Mine is on http://www.doctorwhoworld.net/doctors for example if you search for "daleks" or "bbc audio" it takes you to the index page.

I have followed guides on here but I am still at a stuck point as to why pages will not be found by the search system - it is pages rather than posts I am using for help with the code going forward.

The second question is I am getting lot of white space on top and left can anyone suggest how to minimise.

Comment: What in the name of Gallifrey are you trying to ask here? Slow down, compose your thoughts into a single question, and provide more details as to what your problem is, what you expect, what you're seeing, and how you've attempted to address the problem.

Comment: HI there. I've amended your question to make it clearer that your search system is not working. However, we need a great deal more technical detail. Is your WP installation a stock install? I am not sure if pages are included in the search system - maybe this is only posts? That would be worth researching first. I would advocate removing the secondary questions about the aesthetics and colour - that's an entirely different conversation. You can ask a question about it if you are stuck on how to remove the white space, but we'd need to see the relevant HTML and CSS in the question.

Comment: [This site](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-exclude-pages-from-wordpress-search-results/) says "By default, WordPress Search feature displays published posts and published pages in search results".

Comment: I think this question has been abandoned without requested updates, so voting to put on hold as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see the problem. Your WordPress URL is not at the root of the domain, so you need to change your settings. Go to this page in your admin system:

```
Settings > General
```

Look at your `Site Address (URL)`, which will probably be `http://www.doctorwhoworld.net/`. You need this to be `http://www.doctorwhoworld.net/doctors`, so that the search is carried out on the right home page.

Comment: thanks but I want it to find anything within the whole website not just a specific page.

Comment: @ahearne: it looks to me like the website at `/` is not a WordPress site. The WP installation is at `/doctors/`, and if you make the repair as I suggest, it will work for all WordPress posts and pages. It will not be able to index or search pages outside of the WP system.